# Предполагайте добрые намерения

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, справка, нормы-поведения

Каждый день мы, сообщество увлечённых разработчиков, помогаем нашим коллегам находить ответы на их вопросы, создавая для всех русскоязычных программистов невероятно важный актив. Stack Overflow — двухсторонняя платформа:

1. Изучающие — люди, столкнувшиеся с технической проблемой — задают свои вопросы.
2. Знатоки — люди, знающие как решить подобную проблему — отвечают коллегам.

(Каждый из нас в чём–то знаток, в чём–то — изучающий. Вместе — мы сообщество Stack Overflow на русском.)

Подобная схема создаёт много взаимодействий между людьми разной культуры, разной квалификации, с разными стандартами качества. Это может привести к «трениям». В подобные сложные минуты очень важно помнить, что мы все собрались на сайте с добрыми намерениям — поделиться знаниями и своим опытом с другими людьми, чтобы все, кто столкнётся с подобными проблемами в будущем, не тратили время на публикацию вопроса снова и снова.

Как оказалось, в [Нормах поведения сообщества](/conduct) нет упомянутой выше, и являющейся ключевой для нашего сообщества фразы — «**предполагайте добрые намерения**». Эта фраза когда–то была на странице справки «будьте дружелюбны» (`/help/be-nice`), но почему–то потерялась с переходом к Нормам. Давайте вместе исправим недоразумение!

Коллеги, пожалуйста, предложите место, где бы вы хотели её видеть на текущей странице Норм? В какой формулировке?

Comment: "Если складывается ситуация, в которой вы не можете более оставаться дружелюбным, прекратите разговор вовсе." и получите предупреждение за отказ от общения, согласно новым правилам? ;)

Comment: @edem Подскажите, что еще за такие новые правила?

Comment: @edem новых правил пока нет, давайте не будем спекулировать )

Comment: NicolasChabanovsky @Suvitruf это был наглядный пример для правила "Избегайте сарказма и будьте осторожны с шутками — письменная речь плохо передаёт тон высказываний.")

Comment: @edem ох не надо про сарказм, больная тема...

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335010/309650

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335026/309650

Comment: @Qwertiy Отлично! Спасибо! Может Нормы везде обновятся, а не только у нас.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В предлагаемом разделе правил (*[нормы поведения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/conduct)*), текст можно добавить в абзац с заголовком

**Будьте дружелюбными и доброжелательными.**

Получится вот такой текст:

> Предполагайте добрые намерения всех участников, избегайте сарказма
>   и будьте осторожны с шутками — письменная речь плохо передаёт тон
>   высказываний. Если складывается ситуация, в которой вы не можете более
>   оставаться дружелюбным, прекратите разговор вовсе.

Кроме раздела [нормы поведения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/conduct), предлагаемый текст можно вставить также прямо в [тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour), вот в этот раздел правил

> Улучшайте сообщения с помощью правок или комментариев

прямо в середину фразы

> Мы здесь ради знаний. Будьте дружелюбны и полезны другим!

Получится:

`Мы здесь ради знаний. Предполагайте добрые намерения всех участников, будьте дружелюбны и полезны другим!`

Comment: Отличное замечание про Тур. Добавил в оба места (правда, без «всех участников»). Большое спасибо! =)

Answer (score 17):

Может быть, она неспроста потерялась?

Есть такое субъективное ощущение, что «Нормы» основаны на совсем другом предположении: «какими бы ни были ваши намерения, вы можете быть наказаны за своё поведение».

«Нормы» могли бы рассказывать о том, как у нас принято вести себя, встречать новичков, разрешать конфликты и так далее. Но нет, там список запретов и описание процедуры последовательного наказания.

Грустно это всё.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем сложность? Давайте исправим недостаток! =)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335010/309650

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335026/

Comment: @Qwertiy ага, я давно плюсанул тот ответ.

Comment: @PashaPash и этот вопрос тоже плюсанул. :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky по теме: а как мы его исправим? Выкинем текущие нормы/кодекс и напишем новые? Вряд ли это возможно. Нормы написало не сообщество, а сотрудники SO.

Answer (score 0):

Многие правила и ограничения, принимаемые в обществах, как правило, преследуют вполне определённые цели. Правила и ограничения, принятые *ради смутных и малопонятных целей*, обществом, зачастую воспринимаются как ущемление их прав и свобод: собственно, почему нельзя? А что тут такого? и т.п.

В связи с вышесказанным, предлагаю обратить внимание не столько на само направление "быть дружелюбным", сколько на цели и выгоды, ради которых это "правило" имеет место быть здесь.

Например, причина, дабы "избегать трений", для некоторых людей вообще не имеет никакого смысла, ибо, возможно, они вполне себя хорошо чувствуют в таких случаях. Для них можно добавить пояснение наподобие:

> Когда вы хамите в ответ на замечания, касательно качества вашего
>   вопроса, сделанные вам другим участником, вместо того, чтобы
>   пересмотреть его содержание, вы таким образом увеличиваете вероятность
>   того, что против вас будет настроена большая часть мимо проходящих
>   пользователей, которые легко могут проголосовать против вашего
>   вопроса? Чем это плохо? Ну, например, вы не успеет сдать (выполнить)
>   учебное задание, возможно получите неуд, вас отчислят, вам придётся
>   восстанавливаться, а это траты по времени, по деньгам. Стоит ли ваше
>   **хамство** таких затрат? Решать, конечно, вам, но будучи дружелюбным, у вас будет больше возможностей относительно получения помощи от
>   участника данного сообщества.

**Обновление**

> Как оказалось, в Нормах поведения сообщества нет упомянутой выше, и
>   являющейся ключевой для нашего сообщества фразы — «предполагайте
>   добрые намерения».

Что же касается этого высказывания, то, на мой взгляд, она весьма однобока из-за самого "предположения" о добром намерение. Ведь у людей могут быть совсем разные намерения, которые впрочем нам неизвестны, но тогда зачем вообще всё это разнообразие намерений обозначать как добрые? Изначально неверное предположение может привести к неверным действиям впоследствии.

Comment: "для некоторых людей вообще не имеет никакого смысла". Дело не в этом, а в том, что многие просто не понимают, что делают не так. Это ооочень давняя история с "бинайсом", "вредноносным шумом" и т.д. Сложно следовать правилам, если основополагающие термины не формализованы.

Comment: @Suvitruf ну я не просто так поставил слово "например" или вы считаете что такого поведения из-за этого не может быть и нет здесь?

Comment: @Suvitruf согласен, сложно, но, как правило, люди вполне себе осознают, что они хамят и безо всяких точно расписанных показателей оного поведения.

Comment: Когда человек хамит осознанно - это обычно видно. Сложнее, когда человек истинно не понимает, что задевает кого-то, но модераторам, в случае тревоги, нужно как-то реагировать.

Comment: @edem правило "Предполагайте добрые намерения" не означает "делайте домашки". Оно означает, что если вы видите вопрос, в котором нет попыток решения, и этот вопрос не является грубой копипастой из учебника в стиле "сделайте для меня, быстро!" - то стоит предполагать, что топикастер пытался решить проблему сам, не смог, и просит помощи. Просто не смог оформить вопрос как следует (не привел код, налажал с формулировкой) - такое же регулярно случается.

Comment: То же самое с посылами "на фриланс" - нельзя посылать топикастера "на фриланс", если вопрос - не предложение работы. Причем это правило работает (должно работать( в обе стороны - если кто-то начинает посылать новичков в гугл - его не забанят за нарушение, а предположат, что он хотел добра, просто не смог оценить негативных сторон таких посылов.

Comment: @PashaPash звучит как ругательство "слово", которым вы называете вопрошающего. Надеюсь, вы его не используете напрямую по отношению к ним...

Comment: @edem вы о слове "топикастер"? регулярно использую. если оно не нравится лично вам - могу не использовать в адрес лично вас. в адрес остальных - извините, на мое усмотрение.

Comment: Конечно, на ваше, ну а для тех, кто читает это сообщение, также можете попросить лично @PashaPash, дабы он не использовал его по отношению к вам.

Comment: @PashaPash а что означает слово "топикастер" ??? 0_о

Comment: @timob256 https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: "Корень: -топикастер-." подняло настроение)